# How to prevent an UITableViewCell's content from disappearing when scrolling horizontally

Tags: ios, uitableview, horizontal-scrolling

### General Description

I have 3 UITableViews that have a not-so-big space to exist and have to be scrolled horizontally, so I use UIScrollViews for their titles, and then I use their contentOffset to keep them scrolling together. Every table has 1 prototype cell with its own custom class.

This is the structure of the ScrollViews:

```
scrollView
    //The next objects apply only to the tables with a predefined number of labels (2 of 3)
    view
        label1
        label2
        label3
        label4
```

This is the structure of the TableViews:

```
tableView
    tableViewCell
        contentView
            view
                //Case 1: They have labels here (2 of 3 tables),
                //Case 2: The labels are created here too but programatically, according to a web service result (1 of 3 tables)
```

I use the cellForRowAt function to 1) set the text of the labels or 2) create an undefined number of labels programatically, set their text and add them with `cell.view.addSubview(label)`.

The tables frame width is 205px, but the contentSize (which I set on the cellForRowAt function) is usually wider than that (especially on the one with an undefined number of labels). The **problem** comes when I scroll horizontally (vertically has no problems so far), because at the exact moment when the table contentOffset reaches 205px, all the labels there disappear. If I change the width of the table frame, the labels disappear at the match of the contentOffset with that new width, and this happens with the 3 tables. Just like this (with the table frame width = 205):

contentOffset = 204.5

```
 _________________________
|le2  title3  title4  titl|
|-------------------------|
|el2  label3  label4  labe|
|el2  label3  label4  labe|
|el2  label3  label4  labe|
```

contentOffset = 205

```
 _________________________
|e2  title3  title4  title|
|-------------------------|
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
```

If you keep scrolling it does scroll until the end of the final title (like it should). The titles never disappear, only the TableView content.

I have tried setting the `___.frame.size.width` to the required width for the tableViewCell, contentView and view, but that's not helping.

### Code

Take in account that I have other tables so some functions or table validations are used for other tables as well (each one in their own if or case). I also changed the names of the tables, variables, etc. as they are originally quite different and in Spanish, but I hope that they are understandable.

This would be the most relevant code used for one of the tables with an defined number of labels (I exclude things like what happens when a row is selected and so).

#### Class of the View Controller where the Table and ScrollView are

**Outlets and variables**

```
@IBOutlet var titlesScrollView : UIScrollView!
//this is the View inside of the ScrollView
@IBOutlet var titlesSubView    : UIView!
@IBOutlet var dataTable        : UITableView!
var dataArray                  : [JSON] = []
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    titlesScrollView.delegate = self
    dataTable.delegate        = self
    dataTable.dataSource      = self

    titlesScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: titlesSubView.frame.width, height: titlesSubView.frame.height)

    loadTables()
}
```

**loadTables**

```
func loadTables() {
    self.loadData { error in
        //if error == nil continues loading other tables and so
    }
}
```

**loadData**

```
func loadData(onCompletion:@escaping (NSError?)->Void) -> Void {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        WebServices.sharedInstance.getData(/*parameters*/) { (json, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let tempArray = json?["items"].array {
                    self.dataArray = tempArray

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let offset = self.dataTable.contentOffset
                        self.dataTable.reloadData()
                        self.dataTable.contentOffset(offset, animated: false)
                    }

                    onCompletion(nil)
                } else {
                    /*error handling*/
                }
            } else {
                /*error handling*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**numberOfRowsInSection**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch tableView {
        //Other cases...
        case dataTable: return self.dataArray.count
        default: return 0
    }

}
```

**cellForRowAt**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let index = indexPath.row

    if tableView == otherTables {
        ...
    } else if tableView == dataTable {

        let cell      = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! dataCell

        cell.id          = dataArray[index]["id"].intValue
        cell.label1.text = dataArray[index]["value1"].stringValue
        cell.label2.text = dataArray[index]["value2"].stringValue
        cell.label3.text = dataArray[index]["value3"].stringValue
        cell.label4.text = dataArray[index]["value4"].stringValue

        tableView.contentSize = CGSize(width: titlesSubView.frame.width, height: tableView.rowHeight*CGFloat(dataArray.count))
        cell.setWidth(titlesSubView.frame.width)

        return cell

    } else {
        ...
    }

}
```

**scrollViewDidScroll**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let newOffset = scrollView.contentOffset

    switch scrollView.tag {
        //Other cases (for the other ScrollViews and Tables)...
        case titlesScrollView.tag:
            dataTable.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: newOffset.x,
                                               y: dataTable.contentOffset.y), animated: false)
        case dataTable.tag:
            titlesScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: newOffset.x,
                                                      y: titlesScrollView.contentOffset.y), animated: false)
        default:
            ...
    }

}
```

#### Class for the prototype cell of that table ("dataCell")

**Outlets and variables**

```
@IBOutlet var contentViewCell : UIView!
@IBOutlet var viewCell        : UIView!
@IBOutlet var label1          : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label2          : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label3          : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label4          : UILabel!
var id                        : Int!
private var cellWidth         : CGFloat = 0
```

**layoutSubviews**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.frame.size.width = cellWidth
    //Here is where I did set the frame.size.width for the contentView and View too, but it did nothing about my problem
}
```

**setWidth**

```
func setWidth(_ width: CGFloat){
    cellWidth = width
}
```

Let me know if you need me to post any other detail, and sorry for any English-related mistake.